# convert ipython notebook to python without ipython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, travis-ci

Is there an easy way to convert an ipython notebook to plain python without using ipython itself (i.e. *not* using `ipython nbconvert --to=python ...`)?

Background: I want to test if there is a syntax error in various ipython notebooks using travis-ci. However, installing ipython from source takes too long and the ubuntu packages are outdated.

Comment: Note that installing on travis with recent pip using wheel should take just a few seconds. And nbconvert can run notebook without converting them to python, just use the --execute flag.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get it to install yesterday. But maybe I should try again...

Comment: Did you `pip install ipython[nbconvert]` <- with the squarebrackets ? Otherwise it might not pull all dependencies.

Comment: `nbconvert --execute` does not fail on a syntax error, so that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Oh, it might need another flag for that, but it is probably a recent addition.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple script that does the conversion. It's probably not fool-proof but works for me. I'd still be happy to hear about a better solution.

Link to script: https://gist.github.com/hannorein/8423ad75547f37bba228